Java 22 Foreign Function & Memory API: traversing structs
I'm trying to use the Foreign Function & Memory API in Java 22 to call into FFmpeg's libavformat. First, I used jextract to generate a binding:
jextract --target-package org.ffmpeg.avformat \
    --output /path/to/src/main/java \
    -I <base include dir> libavformat/avformat.h

My initial goal is to open a video file and get its dimensions. Many FFmpeg functions make use of a struct called AVFormatContext, which is a main context struct that refers to other structs, which refer to other structs, etc. So I need to walk through a few different structs to get the width & height:
struct AVFormatContext {
    unsigned int nb_streams;
    AVStream **streams;
    // etc.
}

struct AVStream {
    AVCodecParameters *codecpar;
    // etc.
}

struct AVCodecParameters {
    int width;
    int height;
    // etc.
}

In C, this would involve something like:
int width  = formatCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->width;
int height = formatCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->height;

Here is my attempt in Java:
try (Arena arena = Arena.ofConfined()) {
    ///////////////////// begin setup ////////////////////////

    MemorySegment formatCtxPtr  = arena.allocate(C_POINTER);
    MemorySegment inputFormat   = MemorySegment.NULL;
    MemorySegment formatDictPtr = MemorySegment.NULL;

    MemorySegment url = arena.allocateFrom("file:/path/to/video.mp4");

    int result = avformat_open_input(formatCtxPtr, url, inputFormat, formatDictPtr);
    if (result != 0) {
        throw new IOException("Couldn't open file");
    }

    MemorySegment formatCtx = formatCtxPtr.get(C_POINTER, 0);

    // Verify the AVFormatContext
    av_dump_format(formatCtx, 0, url, 0);

    ///////////////////// end setup ////////////////////////

    StructLayout formatCtxLayout = (StructLayout) AVFormatContext.layout();

    VarHandle streamsHandle  = formatCtxLayout.varHandle(
            MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement("streams"));
    MemorySegment streamsPtr = (MemorySegment) streamsHandle.get(formatCtx, 0);
    MemorySegment stream     = streamsPtr.getAtIndex(C_POINTER, 0);

    StructLayout avStreamLayout  = (StructLayout) AVStream.layout();
    VarHandle codecParamsHandle  = avStreamLayout.varHandle(
            MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement("codecpar"));
    MemorySegment codecParamsPtr = (MemorySegment) codecParamsHandle.get(stream, 0);
    MemorySegment codecParams    = codecParamsPtr.get(C_POINTER, 0);

    StructLayout codecParamsLayout = (StructLayout) AVCodecParameters.layout();
    VarHandle widthHandle          = codecParamsLayout.varHandle(
            MemoryLayout.PathElement.groupElement("width"));
    int width                      = (int) widthHandle.get(codecParams, 0);
}

Sadly that last call to widthHandle.get() causes: java.lang.InternalError: a fault occurred in an unsafe memory access operation

I'm not familiar with libavformat but jextract should have generated getter (and indexed) getter calls to retrieve each member field of each of those structures, avoiding you need to use Layout/VarHandle. eg see if you have AVFormatContext.streams(formatCtx) etc

It looks like you have one too many dereferences:
MemorySegment codecParams    = codecParamsPtr.get(C_POINTER, 0);

The codecParamsPtr is a AVCodecParameters*, which you then try to load a pointer from. That will however just read the first 8 bytes of the struct as a pointer.
Also, like @DuncG says in the comments, you can just use the getters that jextract generates. This should work:
// AVStream**
MemorySegment streams = AVFormatContext.streams(formatCtx);
// AVStream*
MemorySegment stream = streams.getAtIndex(C_POINTER, 0);

// AVCodecParameters*
MemorySegment codecParams = AVStream.codecpar(stream);

int width = AVCodecParameters.width(codecParams);


Works like magic! Thanks!
